Can this loop / code be optimized to find more items in the sequence?
I am looking at the code snippet for OEIS A067075.
  Do[k = 1; While[Plus @@ IntegerDigits[k^3] != n^3, k++]; Print[k], {n, 1, 6}]

It does okay for the first several iterates, but is very slow thereafter.
Is it possible to optimize this for efficiency and to find more items in the sequence, say the first 10 (8) items?

Do you have Mathematica 14.0 ? You could replace Plus @@ IntegerDigits[k^3] with just DigitSum[k^3].

@flinty, DigitSum is actually slower.

@flinty: Yes, I have the latest, but it looks like that is slower based on Domen's comment.

@Domen wow that's disappointing. Mathematica is full of performance related leaky abstractions like this.

I wonder if IntegerPartitions could be useful here. Maybe something like IntegerPartitions[n^3, {numDigs}, Range[0, 9]] and you keep increasing the number of digits numDigs until you find a number such that a permutation of its digits is a perfect cube. Also numDigs has a lower bound of Ceiling[n^3/9]

Also maybe helpful: for a given integer $a$, the smallest number $b$ that has a digit sum equal to $a$  is :
$$
b ~= ~\left( a \mod 9 \right) \times 10^q + 9 \sum_{i=0}^{q-1} 10^i
$$
where $q$ is the quotient of $\frac{a}{9}$
$$
q = \left\lfloor \frac{a}{9}\right\rfloor
$$
so you can create a lower bound for k^3:
lowerBoundCube[n_] := With[{qr = QuotientRemainder[n^3, 9]},   qr[[2]]*10^qr[[1]] + 9*Sum[10^i, {i, 0, qr[[1]] - 1}]   ]

@ydd: Thanks, I will try exploring these.
